# How to view error log of trigger execution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm getting this message when attempting to INSERT to a table with a trigger. Is there a log where I can view what the trigger execution error is, to help me troubleshoot?

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, do NOT use SSMS to "edit" rows in a table. Write the appropriate DML statement manually and execute them using a query window - you will be able to see all the errors and messages generated by that statement. If you post the trigger, someone might offer a suggestion to solve or avoid the problem. Or you could ask whoever designed the database/wrote the trigger for help.

Comment: @SMor Thank you, I did actually execute an insert statement and the error there was just as vague. I'll see about posting the trigger. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default event viewer to display trigger errors.

You can modify your trigger to show errors without raising SQL errors. Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Some_Trigger_name
   ON  SomeTable
   AFTER  INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    return     
END CATCH;

        
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
GO
```